# Read specific values from text file in python

Tags: python

Here is the data in text file

```
# NOTE: These entries come from the source setup spreadsheet.# Do not alter them here.Instead, edit the $AI_META/source.gsk.xlsx file.#However, if this file has been copied into $AI_SERIAL, then editing it in place is expected.# In that case, you should remove this warning.
gsk.gs_attribute 1D 1Z 7C 0H 0T 0SH
gsk.gs_extract 1D 1Z 7C 1H 0T 0SH
gsk.gsportfolio 1D 1Z 7C 0H 0T 0SH
```

I want to read the 7C of gsk.gs_extract.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Explain what the file is, what format is it? What is `gsk.gs_extract`? What is `7C`? Welcome to the site!

Comment: The format looks like one suited for `awk`

Comment: its a text file

Comment: I want to retrieve 3rd value of 3rd line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
result = ''
for line in data('text.txt', 'r').readlines():
    words = line.split()
    if len(words)>3 and words[0] == 'gsk.gs_extract':
        result = words[3]
print result
```